# using a simple list item <li> what am I doing wrong. background color doesnt show up

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

nothing special container id to li and the background color doesnt show up.  how did I mess this up? this is an  element.

HTML,

```
<section id="page-container">
<ul>
<li><h3>some title</h3>item one</li>
<li><h3>title</h3>several like this</li>

</ul>
</section>
```

CSS,

```
#page-container > li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: #7ABFEB;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

any other tips appreciated!

thanks.

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your selector isn't working is because the `li` elements are *not* direct children of the `#page-container` element.

Either remove the [child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), or you *could* change it to include the `ul` element:

```
#page-container > ul > li:nth-child(2n+1) {}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/h5qbzL6j/)

Perhaps the documentation will clarify things:

> [**8.2. Child combinators**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators)
>
> `div ol > li p`
>
> The above selector represents a `p` element that is a descendant of an `li` element; the `li` element must be the child of an `ol` element; the `ol` element must be a descendant of a `div`.

Comment: ohhhh when you do the > that denotes direct children ONLY?  thank you so much!!!!

Comment: I got it, stupid noob mistake.  thanks a lot I really appreciate it.  Thanks for the follow up deep explanation too!

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're styling direct child of `#page-container` and it's wrong, because `li` element doesn't belong to `#page-container`, it belongs to `ul` inside of it.

Fix:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/skL4gjdw/

```
#page-container ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background-color: #7ABFEB;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're looking for a direct child of `#page-container` just remove `>`

```
#page-container li:nth-child(2n+1) {
   background-color: #7ABFEB;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ohj66j4/)

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
#page-container ul li:nth-child(2n+1) {
      background-color: #7ABFEB;
      padding: 10px;
}
```